# In Javascript is there a function that returns the number of times that a given string occurs?

Tags: javascript, string

In Javascript is there a function that returns the number of times that a given string occurs?
I need to return a numeric value that is equal to the number of times that a given string occurs within a particular string for instance:

```
var myString = "This is a test text"
```

If I had to search for '`te`' in the above string it would return 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very nearly: You can use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Match) to do this:

```
var count = "This is a test text".match(/te/g).length;
```

That uses the regular expression `/te/g` (search for "te" literally, globally) and asks the string to return an array of matches. The array's length is then the count.

Naturally that creates an intermediary array, which may not be ideal if you have a large result set. If you don't mind looping:

```
function countMatches(str, re) {
    var counter;

    counter = 0;
    while (re.test(str)) {
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}

var count = countMatches("This is a test text", /te/g);
```

That uses [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp/Test) to find matches without creating intermediary arrays. (Thanks to kennebec for the comment pointing out that my earlier use of [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp/Exec) in the above created intermediary arrays unnecessarily!) Whether it's more efficient will depend entirely on how many of these you expect to match, since the version creating the one big array will probably be optimized within the `String#match` call and so be faster at the expense of more (temporary) memory use — a large result set may bog down trying to allocate memory, but a small one is unlikely to.

*Edit* Re your comment below, if you're not looking for *patterns* and you don't mind looping, you may want to do this instead:

```
function countMatches(str, substr) {
    var index, counter, sublength;

    sublength = substr.length;
    counter = 0;
    for (index = str.indexOf(substr);
         index >= 0;
         index = str.indexOf(substr, index + sublength))
    {
        ++counter;
    }
    return counter;
}

var count = countMatches("This is a test text", "te");
```

There's no pre-baked non-RegExp way to do this that I know of.

Comment: instead of te can I pass a variable?

Comment: @William: Sure, you can build a RegExp from a string: `new RegExp(theString, g)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp), but you have to escape any special regex characters in the string (this is also true with the literal I supplied, but it's trickier in strings). For instance, to search for `[` you have to specify `\[` in a literal RegExp (`/\[/g`); to do that via a string you have to *further* escape the backslash since you're using it in a string literal, so: `new RegExp("\\[", g)`. You see how that can be more confusing. :-)

Comment: while (re.exec(str)) {
}
This is a lovely method, but it does not avoid creating arrays-
it creates a new one each time you execute the loop.

the match method you show first is a more efficient way to count pattern matches.

Comment: @kennebec: Very good point, my explanation was unclear. I meant that it avoided creating one large interim array. I've gone back and fixed that, thanks. :-)

Comment: @kennebec: And have now used `test` instead. Doh!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation of php's substr_count() in js. May this function bring you much joy...

```
substr_count = function(needle, haystack)
{
 var occurrences = 0;

 for (var i=0; i < haystack.length; i++)
 {
  if (needle == haystack.substr(i, needle.length))
  {
   occurrences++;
  }
 }

 return occurrences; 
}

alert(substr_count('hey', 'hey hey ehy w00lzworth'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to use test to count matches- with a global regular expression it works through a string from each lastIndex, like exec, but does not have to build any arrays:

```
var c=0;
while(rx.test(string)) c++


String.prototype.count= function(rx){
    if(typeof rx== 'string') rx= RegExp(rx,'g');
    var c= 0;
    while(rx.test(this)) c++;
    return c;
}
```